# Applying Measures to Actual Sets in Measure Theory?

Tags: measure-theory

Could I get some help interpreting the following question?

Question:

> Suppose $\nu$ is a measure on Borel sets of $(0,\infty)$ and that $\nu((x, 2x]) = \sqrt{x}$ for all $x > 0$. Find $\nu ((0, 1])$.

Am I supposed to use this measure property?: the measure of the union of countably infinite disjoint subsets of $(0,1]$ is equal to the sum of the measures of these subsets? I.e. am I supposed to find a way to partition $(0,1]$ into countably infinite disjoint subsets and then find the sum of the measure of these subsets?

In general, I am confused as to what it means to apply a measure to a specific set.

Comment: Yes that's the idea

Answer (score 4):

If you write
\begin{align*}
(0,1] = \bigcup_{k\geq 1} (2^{-k},2^{-k+1}] 
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\nu((0,1]) &= \sum_{k\geq 1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^k\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}
\end{align*}